# LINQ query to calculate values from joined collection

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to using LINQ to join collections and peforming calculations. I have the following query which joins a collection of **RailwayStation** objects and **ExpenditureData** objects joined by StationId.

```
var joinedData = (from s in stations join e in expenditureData on s.stationId 
equals e.StationId select s).Distinct();
```

What LINQ do I need to get the top 10 stations which the highest expenditureAmount (which is a property in expenditureData) from the `joinedData` collection I have created?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to group the data by StationCargoCode (a property in
>   Station object) to get the top 10 StationCargoCodes with the highest
>   expenditure data and get the total expenditure data too.

You could try the following query:

```
var joinedData = (from s in stations 
                  join e in expenditureData 
                  on s.stationId equals e.StationId 
                  group by s.StationCargoCode into gr
                  select new 
                  {
                      StationCargoCode = gr.Key,
                      TotalExpenditureAmount = gr.Sum(ed=>ed.expenditureAmount)
                  }).OrderByDescending(sc=>sc.TotalExpenditureAmountExpenditureAmount)
                    .Take(10);
```

Initially we join our data based on the station Id.

Then we group by the joined results based on the StationCargoCode.

After the grouping, we project each group to an anonymous object with two values, one the key used for the grouping and the other the sum of the expenditureAmount for that key.

Last, we order by our results in descending order based on the `TotalExpenditureAmount` and we pick up the first 10.

Comment: Please OP, note the indentation this answer has. Make reading it 10x easier.

Comment: But what happen if an station have multiple max values, I think you could have repeated stations in your solution

Comment: Probably just need to apply .Disctinct first then Apply Orderby and lastly .Take(10)

Comment: `var joinedData = (from s in stations 
                  join e in expenditureData 
                  on s.stationId equals e.StationId 
                  orderby e.expenditureAmount descending
                  select s).Distinct().Take(10);`

Comment: @christos thank you for your reply. I'm trying to group the data by StationCargoCode (a property in Station object) to get the top 10 StationCargoCodes with the highest expenditure data and get the total expenditure data too. I have tried the following but I can't get the syntax right:  `(from s in stations
                  join e in expenditureData
                  on s.stationId equals e.StationId
                  orderby e.expenditureAmount descending
                  select s).Sum(e => e.expenditureData).GroupBy(n => n.expenditureAmount).Take(10); `

Comment: @Theomax You are welcome ! Please check my update and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var joinedData = (from s in stations 
                  join e in expenditureData on s.stationId equals e.StationId into g
                  select new{s,g})
                  .OrderByDescending(v=>v.g.Max(r=>r.expenditureAmount))
                  .Take(10)
                  .Select(v=>v.s);
```

### Update

```
var joinedData = (from s in stations 
                  join e in expenditureData on s.stationId equals e.StationId into g
                  select new{s.StationCargoCodes ,Max=g.Max(r=>r.expenditureAmount)})
                  .OrderByDescending(v=>v.Max)
                  .Take(10);
```

If you want just the `StationCargoCodes` then add a `Select` call at the end like this:

```
.Select(e=>e.StationCargoCodes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this does work but I think I need to add a group by somehow to group by StationCargoCodes (a property in the Station objects). How would I get the top 10 StationCargoCodes with the highest expenditure amounts, from the joined data collection.